# Subjective titles.

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should we treat subjective titles?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/how-should-we-treat-subjective-titles)

It is common that we see titles as

1. "Interesting sum."
2. "Really difficult integral."
3. "Probably an easy
   equation."
4. "Easy inequaility."
5. "Tought binomial sum."

I think these type of titles are no good to the question since they are very subjective (even the system warns for subjectiveness in the title). For such reason, I've edited many and made them informative in hope no one will run into a  "Tough binomial sum." which end up being something relatively easy for the user. I think it does justice to both users which read "Easy integral" and end up with a question asking for a triple integral to be solved, or users that read "Tough sum" and the solution is tradition to them. Also, it helps one actually see what the sum/inequality/[whatever] relates to, so it brings a little more order to the main site.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/how-should-we-treat-subjective-titles

Comment: +1: I think it is a very good idea. Do you think the whole community should do this in a real-time basis, or should it be done after a question has an accepted answer? The latter would stop unnecessary discussions about objections to changing the title, and isn't too much more effort.

Comment: A major problem with these kind of subjective titles is also that it makes it hard to search for duplicates.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin True. Seems this will get closed soon.

Comment: I find it somewhat amusing that this thread has +7 with no downvotes while my thread (which was suggested as a duplicate) has quite the up-down ration (+9/-6 methinks).

Comment: I agree that these kinds of titles make it harder to search for duplicates, but that is not because they are subjective, it is because they are uninformative.  "An integral problem" has no suggestive words, and is no more (or less) informative to me than "An awesome integral problem."

Comment: @Peter Please see the linked duplicate, where many good points are made. The matter is not as simple as it may seem at first glance, since certain subjective words do convey useful information to teachers.